# Gerrit: use gsql can't access gerrit database

Tags: gerrit

I want to do some data visualization for Gerrit, but I can't log in to the corresponding database.
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw67A.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gerrit 3.0 onwards has removed the use of an external database in favor of the git based [noteDb](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/homepage/+/md-pages/docs/Notedb.md) and gsql has been removed

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I am considering how to get the database data of Gerrit to do some visualization work. Do you know how I should get it

Comment: Best to ask here: https://groups.google.com/g/repo-discuss